# Better way to retrieving data from windows azure and json web service

Tags: c#, json, azure, windows-phone

i have application that using await to retrieving data from windows azure, and using it along with retrieving data from json, so first i get data from json for the first row of the list and next list is from windows azure

```
private RootObjectDetail _hereRestDetail= null;
public RootObjectDetail hereRestDetail
{
    get { return _hereRestDetail; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._hereRestDetail, value); }
}
private ObservableCollection<AddressDetail> _hereRestAddressDetail = null;
public ObservableCollection<AddressDetail> hereRestAddressDetail
{
    get { return _hereRestAddressDetail; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._hereRestAddressDetail, value); }
}

private async void UpdateTransportDetail()
{

    try
    {
        isBusy = true;
        isBusyMessage = "Loading web server data...";
        addressItem = await addressTable
            //.Where(placeId = hereRestDetail.placeId )
                    .ToCollectionAsync();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                RootObjectDetail result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectDetail>(e.Result);
                hereRestDetail = result;
                hereRestAddressDetail.Clear();
                hereRestAddressDetail.Insert(0,result.location.address);
                var oc = new ObservableCollection<AddressDetail>();
                foreach (var item in addressItem)
                    hereRestAddressDetail.Add(item);

            }
            else
            {
                isFailed = Visibility.Visible;
                isFailedMessage = "Can't get data from web server, please refresh and make sure your internet data connected";
            }

            isBusy = false;
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(hrefText + transportDetailURL));

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        isFailed = Visibility.Visible;
        isFailedMessage = "Something wrong happen, please refresh";
    }   
}
```

but sometimes i giving me error like failed to connect to database, so maybe anyone can give me some way to making this call more efficient?

Comment: It seems likely that your problem here is in the server side code, not the client. Could you post the server code?

Comment: hmmm? i'm just using this code for getting data from server, i don't do any code in my windows azure server...

Comment: Well someone must have written some code to go on the server, and that's the source of the error, so that's what needs fixing.